# How do I initialize an object of a class?

Tags: java, null, initialization, nullpointerexception

My code is something like:

```
public class Foo {
    public int a;
    Bar[] bar = new Bar[10];

    a = bar[0].baz;
}

public class Bar {
    public int b;

    public Bar () { //I tried doing away with this constructor, but that didn't
                    //fix anything
        b = 0;
    }

    public int Baz () {
        //do somthing
    }
}
```

And I get an error message similar to:

```
Exception in thread "Foo" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

at whichever line in Foo I try to call any function or value of the class Bar. How do I prevent bar[] from being null?

EDIT: After some fiddling, I finally got it fixed, thanks everyone!
However, I couldn't call the constructor to fix things up; I had to create another function and call that function from Main (in my case, class Foo is actually class Main, if that really matters). My final result:

```
public class Foo {
    public int a;
    Bar[] bar = new Bar[10];

    public Foo () { //this constructor wasn't called for some reason... I checked this
                    //by using System.out.println... no message was print onscreen
        for (int a = 0; a < bar.length; a++)
            bar[a] = new Bar();
    }

    public static void initializeFoo () {
        for (int a = 0; a < bar.length; a++)
            bar[a] = new Bar();
    }

    public static void Foo () {
        initializeFoo();
        a = bar[0].baz;
    }
}
```

Anybody want to help me out with that, or am I supposed to create another question? :)

Comment: Same way you always do - initialize it to point to an object on the heap.

Comment: If you want help with your code, you'll have to show us the code that actually causes the problem, not some other code that you believe represents the problem, but misses vital bits and doesn't even compile.

Comment: @Michael Thanks, I'll do that next time

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have allocate memory for the references by writing this `Bar[] bar = new Bar[10];` but who will allocate memory for the array elements? Infact arrays of reference types are initialized with null references.

You need to allocate memory to array elements too:

```
for(int i=0; i<bar.length; ++i)
   bar[i]=new Bar();
```

Answer (score 8):

```
Bar[] bar = new Bar[10];

a = bar[0].baz;
```

The above creates an array of type Bar, but does not populate it with any actual Bar objects. Arrays of reference types are initialized with null references. You need to do this:

```
for(int i=0; i<bar.length; i++) {
    bar[i] = new Bar();
}
```

Comment: thanks! that worked, but for some reason I couldn't get the constructor to get that to work; I had to use that code inside another method

Answer (score 3):

The reason you're getting a NullPointerException is because of this line:

```
a = bar[0].baz;
```

`bar[0]` does not yet exist.

What's happening is that when a `Foo` is being initialized, its default initializers run (like the line mentioned above).  You construct `bar` as an array of `Bar` references, but do not initialize the individual places in the array.  If you want them all to be initialized, you need to do something like this:

```
public Foo() {
    bar = new Bar[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      bar[i] = new Bar();
    }
    a = bar[0].baz;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public class Foo 
{
    public int a;
    Bar[] bar = new Bar[10];

    public Foo()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        {
            this.bar[i] = new Bar();
        }
    }
    a = bar[0].baz();
}

public class Bar 
{
    public int b;


    public int baz() 
    {
        return b;
    }
}
```

Comment: the `b = 0` in the constructor is redundant.
and hard-coding 10 at two places isn't nice ;)

Comment: sure, but it's his code.  i'm just fixing one problem at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Right after `Bar[] bar = new Bar[10]`, your bar array is initialized with null values. So `bar[0]` contains `null` and calling `bar[0].baz` would cause a `NullPointerException`.

You need to populate your array with a statement like `bar[0] = new Bar()`. Or

```
for (int i = 0; i < bar.length; i++) {
    bar[i] = new Bar();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The key issue here is a misunderstanding of [array initialization in Java](http://www.janeg.ca/scjp/lang/arrays.html). The initialization of bar[] will be "10 Bar references which are null".

Here is a corrected example (it does not use 10), though it is not very good Java style for other reasons (e.g. public members):

```
class Foo {
    Bar[] bar = new Bar[] { new Bar(), new Bar() };
    public int a = bar[0].b;
}

public class Bar {
    public int b = 0;

    public static void main(String... args) {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        System.out.println(foo.a);
    }
}
```

This example is closer to the true style of Java:

```
class Foo {
    static final int numBars = 10;
    private Bar2[] bar = new Bar2[numBars];
    private int a;

    public int getA() { return a; }

    public Foo() {
        for (int i = 0; i < numBars; i++) {
            bar[i] = new Bar2(); 
        } 
        a = bar[0].getB();
    }
}

public class Bar2 {
    private int b = 0;
    public int getB() { return b; }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        System.out.println(foo.getA());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Many correct answers to work from. Some issues that I think you might have:

- A constructor for Foo would be
  Foo() { /* ... */ }
  not just placing code anywhere in the class.
- Instead of using a loop yourself, you can use 
  java.util.Arrays.fill(Object[] a, Object val)

Like so:

```
public class Foo {
    public int a;
    Bar[] bar = new Bar[10];

    Foo() {
        java.util.Arrays.fill(bar, new Bar());
        a = bar[0].baz();
    }
}
```

Edit: For your updated question, just call 
    new Foo()
from your 
    main(...)
 method. Also, you can't have a static constructor like you do.

Answer (score 1):

Some answers and comments to your code:

The constructor does not get called on its own, you call it activly with the statement `new Foo()`

Your `initializeFoo()` method does not compile. The method is static and cannot access a non-static class member (like `bar` in your case).

And finally, `public static void Foo()` is not a constructor but a method. A Constructor does not have a return type (`void` in your case).